# Use $match on more than 1 field with aggregate and $lookup

Tags: mongodb, match, lookup

I have the following mongo query.

```
db.ServiceProvider.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind: "$PostCommentUserIDs"
   },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "Parents",
            localField: "PostCommentUserIDs",
            foreignField: "ID",
            as: "ParentDetailsArr"
        }
   },
   {
      $match: { "ParentDetailsArr": { $ne: [] } }
   }
])
```

It gives following result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57245af1588aec5b118b4567"),
    "ServiceProviderID" : 3,
    "Title" : "test",
    "PostedMessage" : "test",
    "TotalComments" : 0,
    "TotalShares" : 0,
    "TotalThanks" : 0,
    "AddedOn" : "2016-04-30",
    "LastModifiedOn" : "2016-04-30 07:12:49",
    "PostAttachment" : {
        "ImagePath" : ""
    },
    "PostCommentUserIDs" : "3",
    "PostComments" : [
        {
            "ID" : "1462000372388480634",
            "UserID" : 3,
            "CommentMessage" : "1",
            "TotalThanks" : 0,
            "AddedOn" : "2016-04-30 07:12:52",
            "LastModifiedOn" : "2016-04-30 07:12:52",
            "CommentAttachment" : {
                "ImagePath" : ""
            }
        },
    ],
    "Subscriber" : [ ],
    "ParentDetailsArr" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("572447e6588aec32108b4569"),
            "ID" : "3",
            "UID" : "0Xb1fHqzR3HZVJWQc8aAbB77UkwSnmasdQrtp9qySVdqipsYs6eC7rEt",
            "Name" : "Chinmay Kulkarni",
            "ProfileImagePath" : "images3_3_1460348144#SIZE#.jpeg"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57246137588aec41118b4567"),
    "ServiceProviderID" : 3,
    "Title" : "test",
    "PostedMessage" : "test",
    "TotalComments" : 0,
    "TotalShares" : 0,
    "TotalThanks" : 0,
    "AddedOn" : "2016-04-30",
    "LastModifiedOn" : "2016-04-30 07:39:35",
    "PostAttachment" : {
        "ImagePath" : ""
    },
    "PostCommentUserIDs" : "3",
    "PostComments" : [
        {
            "ID" : "14620019791507102321",
            "UserID" : 3,
            "CommentMessage" : "1",
            "TotalThanks" : 0,
            "AddedOn" : "2016-04-30 07:39:39",
            "LastModifiedOn" : "2016-04-30 07:39:39",
            "CommentAttachment" : {
                "ImagePath" : ""
            }
        },
    ],
    "Subscriber" : [ ],
    "ParentDetailsArr" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("572447e6588aec32108b4569"),
            "ID" : "3",
            "UID" : "0Xb1fHqzR3HZVJWQc8aAbB77UkwSnmasdQrtp9qySVdqipsYs6eC7rEt",
            "Name" : "Chinmay Kulkarni",
            "ProfileImagePath" : "images3_3_1460348144#SIZE#.jpeg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to modify the above query and add the _id condition to it. So that it only gives me 1 result with matches with given _id.

But not able to crack it through. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$match` takes filter criterion. Add the _id query filter criteria inside $match aggregate function - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

Run the query with below $match condition at last pipeline of your aggregate query.

```
db.ServiceProvider.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind: "$PostCommentUserIDs"
   },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "Parents",
            localField: "PostCommentUserIDs",
            foreignField: "ID",
            as: "ParentDetailsArr"
        }
   },
   {
      $match: { "ParentDetailsArr": { $ne: [] }, "_id" : ObjectId("XXXX") }
   }
])
```